# How to show most recent sign-ups? (for the day, week etc...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that allows users to sign up for a trial period, and when the trial period ends they are converted to paying users. Now, on the admin back end I have a statistics page, but I'm having trouble displaying the daily, and weekly sign ups.

I've tried the following:

statistics_controller.rb

```
@trial_subscriptions = Subscription.where(state: 'trial')
@trial_today = @trial_subscriptions.where(created_at: [Date.today.beginning_of_day, Date.today.end_of_day])
@trial_week = @trial_subscriptions.where(created_at: [Date.today.beginning_of_week, Date.today.end_of_week])
```

and the view:

```
<div class="span4">
    <h3>Free Trial</h3>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Sign-ups</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Today</td>
          <td><%= @trial_today.count %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Week</td>
          <td><%= @trial_week.count %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td><%= @trial_subscriptions.count %></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

The controller code returns zero, even though one user signed up today...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@trial_subscriptions.where(:created_at => (Date.current.midnight)..(Date.current.next.midnight) )
```

Comment: hmm.. irb(main):005:0> @trial_subscription.where(created_at: (Date.current.midnight)..(Date.current.next.midnight) )
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass

Comment: do not use 'irb', cd your project, and use 'rails c'

Comment: ok got it!!     @trial_week = @trial_subscriptions.where(created_at: (Date.today.beginning_of_week)..(Date.today.end_of_week) )